# mysql datbaset error

Tags: mysql

When I try to import locally database, the following error happens:
[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: what query you tried??

Comment: Guys, I really can not understand how it is possible that you can not see that query in picture...

Comment: [**Please don't post your code as an image.**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)

Answer (score 2):

Use `ENGINE = InnoDB` instead of `TYPE = InnoDB`.

Comment: will i put this command after importing database from my pc to the server ?

Comment: You need to modify the exported .sql file so that instead of TYPE = InnoDB, it says ENGINE = InnoDB.

Comment: sir , you mean i open the exported .sql on any text editor and make this modification?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to replace TYPE = INNODB with ENGINE = INNODB

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-innodb-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

`TYPE = InnoDB` has been removed, Use `ENGINE = Innodb` instead.

See: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17501